# How does one find and replace text in all open files with jed?

Tags: editors, text-processing

How does one find and replace text **in all open files** with [jed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JED_%28text_editor%29)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about jed, but [Regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) does wonders. It's super easy to use, allows you to cherry-pick or just replace all.

Answer (score 1):

While I know nothing about that editor, maybe you could map a command to a key combination like it is possible in ~/.vimrc. You'd need something like

```
sed -i 's/THIS/WITH THAT/g' $FILE1 $FILE2 $FILE3
```

Your editor probably provides variables for the files you have currently open.